# Can I dynamically select fields in a database using parameterised SQL?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database table, USER_OPTIONS, containing a field for each of a variety of options in an application, it looks effectively as follows:

```
USER_ID | OPTION_1 | OPTION_2 | OPTION_3 | ... | OPTION 20
----------------------------------------------------------
 100    | true     | true     | false    | ... | false 
 101    | true     | true     | false    | ... | false 
 102    | false    | false    | false    | ... | true 
 ... etc etc
```

My application then wants to fire off an AJAX request to make adjustments to this table.

The information sent via AJAX is an array of database fields which have been changed, and their new values (in JSON format), e.g.

```
$my_new_settings === {
    'OPTION_1' : 'false',
    'OPTION_2' : 'false'
    'OPTION_20' : 'true'
}
```

My plan was then to use a parameterised SQL query along the lines of

```
$query_string = "UPDATE `USER_OPTIONS` 
               SET ? = ? 
               WHERE  
               `USER_ID` = ? 
               LIMIT 1 ;";

$my_user_id = 100;
$my_field_for_updating = "OPTION_1";
$my_new_field_value = "false";

if ( $query = $mysqli->prepare($query_string) ) {

    $query->bind_param("sss", $my_field_for_updating, $my_new_field_value, $my_user_id);
    $query->execute();
    $query->close();

}
```

And then iterate through the associative array to grab each other pair of `$my_field_for_updating` and `$my_new_field_value` from `$my_new_settings`.

However.

I have subsequently [discovered the following in the php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

("markers" are the term used for the "?" variables in the parameterised SQL query)

> Note:
>
> The markers are legal only in certain places in SQL statements. For
>   example, they are allowed in the VALUES() list of an INSERT statement
>   (to specify column values for a row), or in a comparison with a column
>   in a WHERE clause to specify a comparison value.
>
> **However, they are not allowed for identifiers (such as table or column
>   names)**, in the select list that names the columns to be returned by a
>   SELECT statement, or to specify both operands of a binary operator
>   such as the = equal sign. The latter restriction is necessary because
>   it would be impossible to determine the parameter type. It's not
>   allowed to compare marker with NULL by ? IS NULL too. In general,
>   parameters are legal only in Data Manipulation Language (DML)
>   statements, and not in Data Definition Language (DDL) statements.

Which has thus ruined my proposed solution.

My next idea was to have an SQL query that updated ALL the fields in the database, but to only include the newly updated field values. However I discovered that this would require a magic "do nothing" variable to assign to the "markers" for fields for which I have no data.

```
$query_string = "UPDATE `USER_OPTIONS` 
                   SET `OPTION_1` = ?,
                   SET `OPTION_2` = ?,
                   SET `OPTION_3` = ?,
                   ...
                   SET `OPTION_20` = ?
                   WHERE  
                   `USER_ID` = ? 
                   LIMIT 1 ;";

$my_user_id = 100;
$my_new_OPTION_1_value = 'false';
$my_new_OPTION_2_value = 'false';
$my_new_OPTION_20_value = 'true';
$magic_do_nothing_value = ????;

if ( $query = $mysqli->prepare($query_string) ) {

    $query->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssssss", 
       $my_new_OPTION_1_value, 
       $my_new_OPTION_2_value,
       $magic_do_nothing_value,
       $magic_do_nothing_value,
       ...
       $magic_do_nothing_value,
       $my_new_OPTION_20_value,
       $my_user_id
    );
    $query->execute();
    $query->close();

}
```

However, I am unaware of what the `$magic_do_nothing_value` might actually be (and found it hard to google). Everything I tried either threw an error or was interpreted as 'false'.

So my first question is: Is there a value which a MYSQL database accepts as a signal for *"do nothing"*?

Assuming there isn't and moving on from this, my next thought was then to drag all the current values out of the database for the given `USER_ID`, amend these with the changes in `$my_new_settings` and then update the database accordingly with ALL the fields.

However this seems like a lot of unnecessary work, especially compared with my first solution.

Which leads me here to ask for a better one!

Thanks a lot for any thoughts you might have, I'm really interested to hear them. This is running on PHP 5.2 and a basic MySQL 5.0.92 database.

Comment: You could use `SET option_22 = IFNULL( ?, option_22 )` as workaround, and specify `NULL` as magic_do_nothing_values. It might however make sense to utilize an existing DAL or ORM instead to generate the proper SQL command rather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply build the SQL dynamically and then bind the parameter values as you have done already. Here's an example using a class to handle a dynamic number of parameters (class taken from PHP documentation). Please note I haven't tested the code, but the logic should be clear anyway.

```
// This class will store the value for each query parameter
class BindParam {
  private $values = array(), $types = '';

  public function add($type, &$value) {
    $this->values[] = $value; 
    $this->types .= $type; 
  } 

  public function get() {
    return array_merge(array($this->types), $this->values); 
  } 
}

$my_new_settings = array(
    'OPTION_1' => 'false',
    'OPTION_2' => 'false',
    'OPTION_20' => 'true',
)


$bind_param = new BindParam();

$query_arr = array("UPDATE `USER_OPTIONS`");

// This loop will build the query and store each parameter value in bin_param instance
foreach($my_new_settings as $field_name => $field_value) {
  $query_arr[] = sprintf('`%s` = ?', $field_name);
  $bind_param->add('s', $field_value);
}

$query_arr[] = 'WHERE `USER_ID` = ?';
$query_arr[] = 'LIMIT 1 ;";

// Put all pieces together, forming an SQL command
$query_string = implode(' ', $query_arr);

$my_user_id = 100;
$my_field_for_updating = "OPTION_1";
$my_new_field_value = "false";

if($query = $mysqli->prepare($query_string)) {
  // Bind all parameter values saved earlier
  call_user_func_array(array($query, 'bind_param'), $bind_param->get())

  $query->execute();
  $query->close();
}
```

Comment: My fear with dynamically creating the query like this (ie string concatenation) is potential vulnerability to SQL injection

Comment: You can always sanitize the field names before building the query, which would eliminate such risk. In a "rough" way, you could keep an array of the fields the table contains, so that you're sure you don't get any arbitrary stuff in it.

Comment: In any case, if you use a "dynamic query building" approach, you'll always be exposed to the risk of SQL injection, unless all the pieces of your query come from a safe place. Your only other option would be to use a full static query (as you've done already), which will have the drawback of an added overhead to manage the missing values.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i didn't start using mysli or PDO yet (lazy me :) )
But i'd implement this function to use when i need to insert to or update a mysql table.
You may not use directly because of your mysqli based usage but may give you an idea.
Looks up fieldnames of table and matches them with the given array keynames (even with the specified prefix) also you need to indicate key field for updates in $sql_condition and $exceptions for filtering unwanted datas to be inserted.

in my usage keynames were starting with "the_" 
and if starts with "t_" automatically ignored.

```
  function q_put2($data_array=array() ,$table, $exceptions = '', $sql_type = 'insert', $sql_condition = NULL) {
      if($sql_condition!=NULL) $table_columns_filter=$sql_condition;
else $table_columns_filter="";
$table_columns_qs="SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table ;";
$table_columns_rs=mysql_query($table_columns_qs);

while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($table_columns_rs)){
   $table_columns[]=$row[0];
} 

$fields = '';$values = '';
foreach ($data_array as $field => $value) {
if(substr($field,0,4)=="the_")$field=substr($field,4);
    if(substr($field,0,2)!="t_" && !strstr($exceptions,$field) &&  in_array($field,$table_columns)){
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        if ($sql_type == 'insert') {
        $fields .= "$field, ";
        $values .= "'$value', ";
        }
        else {
            $fields .= "$field = '$value', ";
        }
    }
}
$fields = preg_replace('/, $/', '', $fields);
$values = preg_replace('/, $/', '', $values);

if ($sql_type == 'insert') {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
}
elseif ($sql_type == 'update') {
 if (!isset($sql_condition)) {
   echo 'ERROR: You must enter a sql condition!';
   exit;
 }
 $sql = "UPDATE $table SET $fields WHERE $sql_condition";}
else {
 echo 'ERROR: Invalid input for argument $sql_type: must be "insert" or "update"';
 exit;
}
if ($q_select_rs=mysql_query($sql)) {
return true;
} 
else 
{
return false;
}
}
```